# When the mouse is hovering over a table row, how can I change both the row's background color and the fill color of a corresponding SVG path?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My webpage dynamically generates a table with table rows of the class `tableTr` and contains a SVG image within the HTML code with paths of the class `pathClass`.

Using JavaScript, upon hovering the mouse over a table row, the background color of the row should change, as well as the fill color of the corresponding shape; both revert back to normal once the mouse is moved off the table row.

The paths should not change fill color when the mouse hovers over them; this does not work in reverse.

I am totally stumped about what approach to use. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--the dynamically generated table with the rows 
            that need highlighted-->
            <table id="resultsTable"></table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <object id="map">
                <svg id="mapSvg">
                    <path id="c000000" class="pathClass"></path>        
                </svg>
            </object>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My JS code that dynamically generates the table is as follows:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("class", "resultsTable");
table.setAttribute("id", "resultsTable");
for (var q = 0; q < 3143; q++){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("class", "tableTr");
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.setAttribute("class", "tableTd");
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    td2.setAttribute("class", "tableTd");
    if (q % 2){
        td1.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#DEEAF6");
        td2.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#DEEAF6");
    } else {
        td1.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#FFFFFF");
        td2.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#FFFFFF");
    }        
    if (q){
        var text1 = document.createTextNode(results[q-1][0]);
        var text2 = document.createTextNode(results[q-1][1]);
        td1.appendChild(text1);
        td2.appendChild(text2);
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        table.appendChild(tr);
   } else {
       var text1 = document.createTextNode("County");
       var text2 = document.createTextNode("Deviation from Optimal");
        td1.appendChild(text1);
        td2.appendChild(text2);
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        table.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("resultsCell").appendChild(table);
```

Comment: There is no need to use javascript if you want to change the row color on hover, css selector will do. With respect to the svg, it depends whether the svg is descendant of the row or not and in that case, I think you should include your code, so it's clear to me to provide a correct answer.

Comment: @Abdelrahman I would like both the row itself to highlight and trigger an action (highlight a corresponding shape in a SVG). I need to use JS, AFAIK, to do so. The SVG is independent of the rows; the table is dynamically generated, while the SVG is merely recolored in response to the data in the newly-generated table.

Comment: Ivan, we're happy to try and help but for us to do so we need to see the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code you're working with (stripped down to the minimum code necessary to reproduce your problem/situation). Have a look at the "*[ask]*" guidance (as well as the previous link to the ""minimal complete verifiable example"" guidance).

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, new to Stack Overflow. I've added any relevant code snippets I could think of.

Comment: @IvanFox you forgot to add the css code and the HTML doesn't have content, currently the result is blank as there is no styling. Try use code snippet where you add HTML, CSS, Javascript and can run them inside the question, that way you can test your code before posting them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to achieve is similar to the following where every country in the map is highlighted when the row corresponding to it in the tabled is hovered over while the country shape (country path in html) isn't highlighed when you hover over it. Expand to full page for clear view.

```js
var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll(".results-table tr");

console.log(tableRows);

tableRows.forEach((row) => {
  row.addEventListener("mouseover", colorCountry);
  row.addEventListener("mouseout", resetCountryColor);

})

function colorCountry(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "lightgray";
  document.querySelector(`#${e.currentTarget.dataset.country}`).style.fill = "green";
}


function resetCountryColor(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "white";
  document.querySelector(`#${e.currentTarget.dataset.country}`).style.fill = "#f2f2f2";
}
```

```css
.results-table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* .results-table tr:hover{ 
  background: lightgray;
} */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="results-table">
        <tr data-country="EG">
          <td>Egypt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="SD">
          <td>Sudan</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="ER">
          <td>Eritrea</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="SO">
          <td>Somalia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="ET">
          <td>Ethiopia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="DJ">
          <td>Djibouti</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="LY">
          <td>Libya</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-country="SS">
          <td>South Sudan</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <object class="map">
        <svg class="map-svg" height="350px" pretty_print="False" style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke:#000; fill: none;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1001" width="400px">
          <sodipodi:namedview pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" objecttolerance="10" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-width="640" inkscape:window-height="480" id="namedview68" showgrid="false" inkscape:zoom="0.33342098" inkscape:cx="603.38628" inkscape:cy="543.55784" inkscape:window-x="1456" inkscape:window-y="314" inkscape:window-maximized="0" inkscape:current-layer="svg2" />
          <defs id="defs4">
            <style type="text/css" id="style6">
              path {
                fill-rule: evenodd;
              }

            </style>
          </defs>
          <metadata id="metadata8">
            <views id="views10">
              <view h="1001" padding="0" w="1000" id="view12">
                <proj flip="auto" id="robinson" lon0="100.0" />
                <bbox h="1210.83" w="1011.29" x="-258.56" y="-626.99" id="bbox15" />
              </view>
            </views>
            <rdf:RDF>
              <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
              </cc:Work>
            </rdf:RDF>
          </metadata>

          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="DJ" data-name="Djibouti" data-id="DJ" d="m 820.3,358.7 -5.3,-3.8 6.8,-3.3 0.1,-5.7 -3,-4.3 -3.6,3.4 -5.2,-1.2 -4,6.1 -3.9,6.5 1.1,3.8 0.3,4.2 6.8,0.2 2.9,-0.9 2.8,2.4 4.2,-7.4 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />
          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="EG" data-name="Egypt" data-id="EG" d="m 628.8,88.1 -11.9,-4 -11.5,-3.7 -15.6,0.2 -3.7,6.6 2.2,5.9 -2.4,8.5 4.2,11.2 2.9,49.2 2.2,50.9 48.1,0 46.4,0 47.4,0 -2.2,-2.8 -14.7,-12.4 -0.9,-9 2.2,-2.4 -11.6,-15.3 -4.4,-7.9 -4.9,-7.5 -10.5,-21.6 -8.4,-13.9 -6.1,-14.5 1.1,-1.3 10.1,19.8 5.8,6.2 4.3,4.4 2.5,-2.4 2.7,-7.2 1.6,-10.4 2.8,-5.6 -1.5,-3.5 -8.5,-20.1 0,0 -5.4,3.4 -9.2,-0.8 -9.6,-3.2 -2.3,4.5 -3.8,-6.8 -8.5,-1.8 -10.2,1.2 -4.5,3.9 -8.6,4.4 -5.6,-2.2 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />
          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="ER" data-name="Eritrea" data-id="ER" d="m 777.6,303.8 -7,-6.8 -4,-12.7 -7.8,-16 -5.7,7.9 -8.8,2.3 -3.6,4.2 -0.7,9.2 -4.3,20.3 1.5,5.6 14.3,2.9 3.3,-10.4 7.6,6.3 7,-3.2 3,2.9 8.3,0.1 10.8,5.6 3.4,4.8 5.5,4.4 5.4,8.1 4.3,4.5 5.2,1.2 3.6,-3.4 -6.2,-4.2 -4,-4.7 -6.9,-8 -7.1,-7.9 -17.1,-13 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />
          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="ET" data-name="Ethiopia" data-id="ET" d="m 754.8,310.3 -3.3,10.4 -14.3,-2.9 -1.4,11.9 -4.5,13.6 -7.1,6.8 -4.8,10.6 -1.1,5.7 -5.6,3.8 -3.3,14.5 0.1,1.7 0.4,10.8 -1.8,4.2 -6.4,0.3 -4,7.9 7.5,1 6.3,6.7 2.2,5.6 5.7,3.2 7.4,15 6.4,2.4 0.1,7.7 4.2,4.6 8.5,0 15.7,11.7 3.8,0.2 2.9,-0.4 2.7,1.6 8.2,1.1 3.5,-5.8 11.1,-5.8 4.9,4.7 8.4,0 3.3,-4.4 7.8,-0.2 10.7,-9.8 15.9,-0.6 33.5,-41.5 -10.3,0.1 -40.3,-16.4 -4.8,-5 -4.6,-6.6 -4.8,-7.7 2.5,-4.9 -2.8,-2.4 -2.9,0.9 -6.8,-0.2 -0.3,-4.2 -1.1,-3.8 3.9,-6.5 4,-6.1 -4.3,-4.5 -5.4,-8.1 -5.5,-4.4 -3.4,-4.8 -10.8,-5.6 -8.3,-0.1 -3,-2.9 -7,3.2 -7.6,-6.3 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />
          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="LY" data-name="Libya" data-id="LY" d="m 589.8,80.6 -3.1,-4.5 -11.7,-1.6 -3.9,-2.4 -4.4,0 -4.4,-6.2 -15.9,-2.8 -7.9,1.8 -7.9,6.5 -3.3,6.7 3.4,10.6 -5.3,6.3 -5.5,3.6 L 507,91.7 490.3,86 479.7,83.3 473.6,71 l -15.7,-6.1 -9.8,-2.3 -4.8,1.2 -13.8,-4.8 -0.3,10.6 -5.6,4 -3.4,4.4 -7.9,5.3 1.5,5.7 -0.9,5.8 -5.6,3.2 4.1,12.2 0.8,6.4 -1.8,11.3 1,6.3 -1.4,7.6 1.3,8.7 -4.6,5.8 7.2,10.1 0.6,5.9 4.3,7.7 5.5,-2.5 9.6,6.4 5.4,8.7 19,6 6.9,7.5 8.3,-5.1 11.9,-7.6 48.4,26.5 48.7,26.5 -0.1,-5.8 13.8,0 -1,-27.7 -2.2,-50.9 -2.9,-49.2 -4.2,-11.2 2.4,-8.5 -2.2,-5.9 3.7,-6.6 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />

          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="SD" data-name="Sudan" data-id="SD" d="m 740,291.9 0.7,-9.2 3.6,-4.2 8.8,-2.3 5.7,-7.9 -6.9,-5.1 -4.8,-3.4 -5.3,-16.5 -2.5,-14.3 2.5,-2.5 -4.7,-13.6 -47.4,0 -46.4,0 -48.1,0 1,27.7 -13.8,0 0.1,5.8 2.4,54.9 -10.5,-0.9 -5.2,10.2 -3,8.5 2.6,3.2 -3.8,4.3 1.5,5.7 -3,5.8 -1.2,5 4.3,-0.8 2.6,5.4 0.3,8 4.6,4.1 -0.1,3.4 1.5,5.9 7.2,8.6 0.1,5.7 -1.9,5.7 0.9,4.3 4.2,4 1,0.7 3.8,-1.6 4.1,-2.6 2.9,-12.3 3.2,-6.4 8.8,-1.9 2.1,3.8 6.5,8 3.3,1.2 4.4,-2.3 8.7,0.4 1.8,2.9 12.1,0 0.3,-2.9 6.3,-2.6 1.1,-4 4.6,-2.9 10.4,8.1 6.2,-1.4 5.8,-10 6.5,-7.6 -1.3,-8.3 -3,-4 7.3,-0.8 0.7,-3 5.7,0.9 -1.2,10.2 1.7,10 6.5,5.5 1.5,4.7 0,6.9 1.7,0.3 -0.1,-1.7 3.3,-14.5 5.6,-3.8 1.1,-5.7 4.8,-10.6 7.1,-6.8 4.5,-13.6 1.4,-11.9 -1.5,-5.6 4.3,-20.3 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />
          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="SS" data-name="S. Sudan" data-id="SS" d="m 707.8,379.2 -1.5,-4.7 -6.5,-5.5 -1.7,-10 1.2,-10.2 -5.7,-0.9 -0.7,3 -7.3,0.8 3,4 1.3,8.3 -6.5,7.6 -5.8,10 -6.2,1.4 -10.4,-8.1 -4.6,2.9 -1.1,4 -6.3,2.6 -0.3,2.9 -12.1,0 -1.8,-2.9 -8.7,-0.4 -4.4,2.3 -3.3,-1.2 -6.5,-8 -2.1,-3.8 -8.8,1.9 -3.2,6.4 -2.9,12.3 -4.1,2.6 -3.8,1.6 8.4,5.4 6.8,5.5 0.1,4.5 8.3,7.2 5.2,6 3.2,8.3 9.2,5.5 2,4.4 7.5,11.4 5.5,1.7 3.2,-2.3 5.7,0.9 6.8,-2.9 2.9,5.9 10.9,9.2 0,0 5,-3.8 7.8,3.1 9.8,-3.3 8.6,0.1 7.4,-6.4 7.4,-8.3 8.1,-9.1 -7.4,-15 -5.7,-3.2 -2.2,-5.6 -6.3,-6.7 -7.5,-1 4,-7.9 6.4,-0.3 1.8,-4.2 -0.4,-10.8 -1.7,-0.3 0,-6.9 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />

          <path class="country" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="SO" data-name="Somalia" data-id="SO" d="m 832.6,372.8 -5.7,-5.8 -2.5,-5.7 -4.1,-2.6 -4.2,7.4 -2.5,4.9 4.8,7.7 4.6,6.6 4.8,5 40.3,16.4 10.3,-0.1 -33.5,41.5 -15.9,0.6 -10.7,9.8 -7.8,0.2 -3.3,4.4 -10.5,15.7 0.4,50.4 7.2,11.4 2.7,-3.3 2.9,-7.3 13.4,-16.7 11.4,-10.6 18.1,-13.7 12.1,-11.2 14.1,-18.9 10.1,-15.5 10,-20.2 7,-17.7 5.4,-15.5 2.9,-14.9 2.4,-5 -0.4,-7.3 0.8,-8 -0.5,-3.9 -4.6,0.1 -5.5,4.7 -6.4,1.4 -5.5,2.1 -3.9,0.2 0,0 -6.9,0.5 -4.2,2.6 -6,0.9 -10.5,4.3 -13.2,1.6 -11.3,3.5 -6.1,0 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2" />
        </svg>
      </object>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. However, I'm not sure how the rows reference SVG paths within the code; how is each row assigned a path?

Comment: @IvanFox If you're svg doesn't change as in my code, I reference the path by id and put data attribute `data-country` in the rows which is the same as the corresponding svg id  in the following `<tr data-country="SS">` so when the hover event activate with data attribute equal to SS, I change background color of path with id "SS". In the hover event, I used `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` as children of the row tag such as colums `<td>` can trigger the hover event and in this case they won't have data attribute `data-country`

Comment: @IvanFox So simply, I'm linking `data-country` custom attribute value with svg path's ids.

Comment: @IvanFox Additional small tip when creating new rows, you don't need to create every child element using javascript `createElement`, you could use template string and put your template html tags in it as writing normal HTML and just create the parent element and append the template HTML to the parent row `tr` element using `innerHTML` method. Such way would make your coding, easier. If the answer stasfies, please mark answer as accepted for the question to be finalized. Happy coding!